# Website was not redirect from non www to https+www

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, 301-redirect, joomla

I'm currently doing www+https redirection where I hope that my website able to redirect from http://example.com to https://www.example.com but it does not work even I have added redirection in .htaccess file. Below is my redirection which I have added in .htaccess file and supposedly able to work since I search everywhere this is the most common redirection that I can found:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Even though I have added this line, and try to type http://example.com, it somehow still does not redirect to https://www.example.com and I have run out of idea. I also did try to add a redirection in https-vhosts.conf and disable it from reading .htaccess file does not work as well.
Below are logs that I manage to get:

```
RewriteCond: input='www.example.com' pattern='^example.com' [NC] => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='/index.php/news-and-events/news-and-events/news' pattern='(/|\\.htm|\\.php|\\.html|/[^.]*)$' [NC] => matched
    RewriteCond: input='D:/wamp64/www/example/index.php' pattern='!-f' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\\%3D)' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='base64_encode.*\\(.*\\)' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='(\\<|%3C).*script.*(\\>|%3E)' [NC] => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='GLOBALS(=|\\[|\\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})' => not-matched
    RewriteCond: input='' pattern='_REQUEST(=|\\[|\\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})' => not-matched
    pass through D:/wamp64/www/example/index.php
init rewrite engine with requested URL /, referer: http://intranet/
```

My SSL was actually configured in https-ssl.conf where I point my certificate at httpd-ssl.conf file. I don't think I need to change my vhosts configuration to 443(currently using VirtualHost *:80) since I have pointed my certificate in httpd-ssl.conf file and my website are now are running https+www. Is just that I want when someone type http://example.com in browser, it will redirect them to https://www.example.com
Please do point me out if I'm doing anything wrong and TIA!